# How can I run a batch-file under windows git-bash console?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, git-bash

How can I run a batch-file uder windows git-bash console.
When I run it I get:

```
user@DESKTOP-DF012sh MINGW64 /c/project-folder 
$ util.bat 
bash: util.bat: command not found
```

Comment: Maybe you need to tell the git-bash console what to use for executing a `.bat` script: `cmd.exe /C util.bat`

Comment: @aschipfl no need. Calling the bat directly works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you mention *where* the bat is.

```
./util.bat
```

By default, a `$PATH` does not include the current folder.

I just tested executing a `.bat` script that way, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I get 'The syntax of the command is incorrect'

Comment: @CraigWilcox was it in a git bash session? Or in a regular CMD?

Comment: A git bash session, of course.

Comment: @CraigWilcox What version of  Git for Windows are you using? I just launched another .bat in a git bash session without any issue.

Comment: I was misled believing it could not run, as using the Tab key for name completion was not suggesting me the `.bat` file name. So I tried copy pasting the full file name as in `./myscript.bat` and hitting the Enter key and it worked and ran the script.